# How to say "Game Changer" in Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, idiom, reference-request

How can we describe the disruptive influence of a new factor/invention/information to a sphere of life? as the English idiom "game changer"?

In particular, it would be great to have a reference for such a description in Classical or Medieval text. We can Imagine Pliny relates a story of a new discovery in past that from ever since things change, or Caesar/Livy speak about new factor now decided to get involved in war which now changing "the game" making it a "new war"; or some description medieval of the press or other invention in a specific field completely revolutionizing it.

I was thinking of things such as *pertubation rerum* but failed to find any references to those.

Comment: The closest counterpart that springs to mind is [*homo novus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novus_homo). It won't work for your purpose as such, but perhaps there's a variation on the theme?

Comment: It should definitely include novus/a/um in the concept, as in _ars nova_ or, as Joonas says, _homo novus_. A superlative, (_res novissima_?) could help, too

Comment: What about do it in like spanish: revolucionario (revolutionary).